# Construction of Kahler Einstein Metric of Poincare Type

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-einstein-metric

I am reading Kobayashi's *Kahler-Einstein metric on an open algebraic manifold*. In this paper he constructs a Kahler-Einstein of Poincare type on an open manifold X' = X\D, where X is projective and D is a smooth divisor such that $K_{X}\otimes[D]$ is ample. He uses continuity method to do this.

In the first part of the proof, he needs to show the following result: $\tilde{\Delta}-Id$ is an isomorphism between $C^{k,\beta}(X')$ and $C^{k-2,\beta}(X')$, here $\tilde{\Delta}$ is the Dolbeault Laplacian with respect to some Kahler-Einstein metric of which the precise form is not too important. We are mainly interested in why $\tilde{\Delta}-Id$ has a bounded converse. He doesn't write too much here, so I have to guess a bit what he really wants to do here. Here is my guess about his thought.

We give a compact exhaustion $\Omega_{1}\subset \Omega_{2}\subset \cdots \Omega_{n}\subset \cdots$. For any $v\in C^{k-2,\beta}(X')$. we solve the following equations:

$$\tilde{\Delta}h_{i} - h_{i} = v  ~~~in ~~\Omega_{i}$$
$$h_{i} = 0 ~~on ~~\partial\Omega_{i}$$
 By maximal principle we get $||h_{i}||_{C^{0}(\Omega_{i})}\leq ||v||_{C^{0}(\Omega_{i})}\leq ||v||_{C^{0}(X')}$. For $j>k>i$, after restriction on $\Omega_{i+1}$, we have:

$$\tilde{\Delta}(h_{j}-h_{k}) - (h_{j}-h_{k}) = 0 ~~on ~~\Omega_{i+1}$$

Then by Schauder estimate:

$$||h_{j}-h_{k}||_{C^{k,\beta}(\Omega_{i})}\leq C||h_{j}-h_{k}||_{C^{0}(\Omega_{i+1})}\leq 2C||v||_{C^{0}(X')}$$

So after restriction on $\Omega_{i}$ $\{h_{j}\}$ is a bounded sequence in $C^{k,\beta}(\Omega_{i})$, so we can find a subsequence of $\{h_{j}\}$ which converges in some $C^{k,\beta'}(\Omega_{i})$, here $\beta'<\beta$. By using a diagonal argument we can find a subsequence of $\{h_{j}\}$ which converges to some element in $C^{k,\alpha}(X')$ where $\alpha<\beta$.

But there are some questions.

First I think we can only get an element in $C^{k,\alpha}(X')$ where $\alpha<\beta$ instead of $C^{k,\beta}(X')$.

Second I am not sure if we can get a good Schauder estimate here. Schauder estimate takes the following form:

$$||h||_{C^{k,\beta}(V')}\leq C(||h||_{C^{0}(V)} + ||Lh||_{C^{k-2,\beta}(V)})$$ where $V'\subset\subset V\subset\mathbb{R}^{N}$.

Notice that $C^{k,\alpha}(X')$ is defined to be $\{f|sup||f||_{C^{k,\beta}(V)}<\infty, V\in \mathcal{V}\}$ where $\mathcal{V}$ is a class of coordicate charts which are quite compatible with the Riemannian structure. In order to get a good Schauder estimate of the form:

$$||h||_{C^{k,\beta}(\Omega_{i})}\leq C(||h||_{C^{0}(\Omega_{i+1})} + ||(\tilde{\Delta}-Id)h||_{C^{k-2,\beta}(\Omega_{i+1})})$$

I think we need to go back to the coordinates, that is to say:

$$||h||_{C^{k,\beta}(\Omega_{i}\cap V)}\leq C(||h||_{C^{0}(\Omega_{i+1}\cap V)} + ||(\tilde{\Delta}-Id)h||_{C^{k-2,\beta}(\Omega_{i+1}\cap V)})$$

for $\forall V\in \mathcal{V}$ such that $V\cap \Omega_{i}\neq \emptyset$. But it is totally possible that $V\subset \Omega_{i}$. Then the last inequality is not likely to be true.

The reasoning above is based on my guess of Kobayashi's idea. It is possible that my guess is wrong. I would be really happy if someone could point out the real thought of Kobayashi.

I am not familiar with Holder space and Schauder estimates on open manifolds. Are there any references which talk about Schauder estimates for $V\subset\subset M$ where $V$ is a compact submanifold with boundary in some Riemannian manifold M?